# Declare variable to be function and have properties in one statement

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to combine the following into one statement:

```js
// Combine from here

const foo = function() {
    return 'hello';
}
foo.world = 'world';

// to here

console.log(foo() + foo.world) // helloworld
```

Comment: I'm assuming that your question implies that `console.log(foo() + foo.world)` is unchangeable?

Comment: I'm only curious if the statements above it are able to be combined.  I don't care about the `console.log...`.

Comment: I understand that, but the `console.log` is the only thing you have defining your constraints. It's not clear what your end-goal is. I'm not sure how far I can go manipulating your function. Can it be a constructor function? `new foo()`? A class?

Comment: As long as I can call `foo()` and it has a property `foo.world` I'm okay with it.  I'm just curious if I can do this in one step, or if I need a factory to build these objects.

Comment: something like `const foo = Object.assign(function() { return 'hello'; }, { world: 'world' })` ? or `foo.world = 'world';` can be inside the function

Comment: @Slai this works!  I can't believe I didn't think of this.  It's still a factory, but at least it's a vanilla one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the property declaration *into* the function.

```js
let foo = function () {
  foo.world = 'world';
  return 'hello';
};
  
console.log(foo() + foo.world)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(foo = () => 'hello').world = 'world'
```

Comment: running this in Chrome console.  `foo()` worlds, but `foo.world` is undefined.

Comment: @Bradd sorry, I made an edit, now foo.world is defined

Comment: it does work now, is it possible to do this with multiple properties though?

Comment: You can use defineProperties: Object.defineProperties( (foo = () => 'hello'), {world: { value:'world'}, universe: {value:'universe'}})

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign statics outside of the function/class declaration. Here is an alternative ES5 version using classes.

```js
class foo {
  constructor() {
    // constructor...
  }
  toString() {
    return 'hello'
  }
}
foo.world = 'world' // static member variables need to be assigned outside, no other way

console.log(new foo() + foo.world) // helloworld
```

Comment: "statics need to be assigned outside, no other way" I think was the answer to my question.  It seems like I would be limited to one static at a time this way as well correct?

Comment: Well, I really mean static member variables. Static methods are actually allowed. Here is a proposal from 2 years ago for adding [static constructor and static member variables](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/proposal-for-a-static-constructor-and-static-member-variables) to JavaScript.